# Encrypting and securing sheets for users

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to lock one sheet to be visible only for a handful of people.

The below macro runs once you open the workbook. It creates a 'check sheet' and runs code to check if people who opened the sheet are on the list.

There is one issue: once you disable macros the mentioned sheet is no longer very hidden and everyone gets access to it.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("OTE ratios").Visible = xlVeryHidden

Dim IFFORMULA As String
IFFORMULA = "=IF(OR(AA1=A2,AA2=AA1, AA3=AA1,AA4=AA1,AA5=AA1,AA6=AA1,AA7=AA1,AA8=AA1),""Yes"", ""No"")"

Sheets.Add.Name = "check"

Worksheets("check").Range("A2").Value = Worksheets("January").Range("A2").Value

Worksheets("check").Range("AB1").Value = IFFORMULA
Worksheets("check").Range("AA1").Value = Application.UserName
Worksheets("check").Range("AA2").Value = "USER1"
Worksheets("check").Range("AA3").Value = " USER2"
Worksheets("check").Range("AA4").Value = " USER3"
Worksheets("check").Range("AA5").Value = " USER4"
Worksheets("check").Range("AA6").Value = " USER5"

'DM goes here
Worksheets("check").Range("AA8").Value = " USER6"

Worksheets("check").Calculate

''''IF statement
If Worksheets("check").Range("AB1").Value = "Yes" Then
    Sheets("OTE ratios").Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

''''remove the sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("check").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("January").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe keep OTE ratios as VeryHidden by default, if a user is authorized to see it, have the macro show it to them. Use a Workbook close event to set it as VeryHidden before saving and closing it.

Comment: Also maybe try working with an array to check if the user is in the list instead of creating/deleting an extra sheet. And let the people who are on the list know they need to enable macros if they wanna see the extra sheet ;)

Comment: What about locking the sheet and using the password on it? I use that to stop people playing with formulae they don't understand.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have used it previously, but the problem is multiple people may work on the same sheet, and that can cause issues when trying to save the workbook

Comment: @SolarMike but will this prevent people to see the sheet they not suppose to see?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe Excel is the wrong tool here?

Comment: Yes, stops my students seeing the answers in my worksheets and the if() I use to say "correct" or not. try it and see.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I was thinking about this for long, and you might be right. Are there any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're going to code the users in VBA code, why don't you do the If check with VBA code, instead of doing it with a formula in a cell?

Second, I think your problem is that you hide the sheet with xlVeryHidden before creating the new sheet, but Excel needs to keep at least one sheet visible. Instead you should first create the new sheet and then hide the old one.

You could also keep the blank sheet visible by default, instead of creating it on open, and the other sheet hidden by default, and decide on open whether to show the hidden sheet or not.

Finally I would like to know why a question is answered in comments instead of adding an answer? All the best.

Comment: Comments are used to clarify what exactly the OP is after, as you can see, the OP has issues with the plausible answers.